# Obtener la duracion de un audio con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de audio web el cual optiene todas las canciones de un directorio y las muestra en pantalla, reproduce, etc.
Mi problema consiste en que no e logrado obtener la duracion del audio sin usar una etiqueta audio o video.
Estas dos funcionan pero empeora la UX pues sin usar la etiqueta audio para cargar el audio y traer su duracion, la carga de 47 canciones tarda poco menos de 40s en cambio al hacer uso de una etiqueta audio que lo cargue y me traiga la informacion de cada uno esto tarda mas de 5 minutos, lo cual es bastante lento.
Quisiera encontrar una forma de hacer esto, pues con java hago uso de

```
long duration = Long.parseLong(mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
```

y obtengo esto, mas con javascript no encuentro la forma de obtener esta información y la necesito. Agradezco sus respuetas

Answer (score 1):

No hay forma de saber la duracion de un audio hasta que como minimo se haya cargado su `metadata`.

por ende, puedes setear el atributo `preload` en su valor `metadata` si solo requieres extraer informacion como el `nombre`, la `duracion`, el tipo `mime` etc.

Setear una etiqueta `audio/video` con su atributo `preload` en su valor `metadata` hara que solo se cargue la `metadata` del recurso. por ende la respuesta es tan sencilla como hacer esto:

**HTML:**

```
<audio src = "recurso.wav" preload = "metadata"></audio>
```

**Javascript:**

En caso de que tu crees `audios` o `videos` pero desde `javascript` para no contaminar el `DOM` entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente desde `JS` fijate como usamos el evento `loadedmetadata` pertenenciente a la etiqueta `HTMLMediaElement` y ademas el atributo `preload` seteado en `metadata` para asi solo cargar los `metadatos`.

Ademas, es muy importante realizar la carga *DESPUES* de haber añadido el evento `loadedmetadata` a nuestra etiqueta video.

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  const archivos = document.getElementById("archivos");
  
  function handleFiles(ev){
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.preload = "metadata";
    video.onloadedmetadata = ()=> console.log(video.duration);
    video.onloadend = ()=> URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[0]);
  }
  
  archivos.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);

}
```

```html
<input type = "file" id = "archivos">
```

De esta manera la carga de la información que te interesa se acelera muchisimo, pues javascript solo tendra que cargar la metadata.

Sin embargo la desventaja de esto es que por supuesto no podras usar la data que es del elemento en si debido a que solo estas cargando su *metadata*.

Si quieres cargar el archivo completo y a la vez poder extraer información cuando este disponible deberás modificar un poco lo que hice, ademas de *NO* usar algo como `FileReader` para leer la información, ya que la carga de la información sera muchisimo mas lenta mediante sus metodos, vamos por pasos:

1.) Setear el atributo preload en `auto` o en `none`, (si lo seteas en none deberas luego ejecutar la funcion `load()` para que se cargue el `video/audio`).

2.) Añadirle al elemento `HTML` el evento `loadend` y `loadedmetadata` *ANTES* de cargarlo.

3.) Para cargar la informacion (`src`) del `video/audio` no uses el `FileReader`
en vez de ello usa los metodos `URL.createObjectURL` y `URL.revokeObjectURL`, el primero usalo para cargar la informacion por medio del `File`, el segundo usalo en el metodo `loadend` si no necesitas ya la informacion para asi liberar memoria, ademas ten en cuenta que esta informacion solo existira y seguira existiendo si el `HTML` hace uso de ella, porque en caso contrario sera descartado automaticamente por el navegador.

4.) Para obtener la `metadata` dentro del metodo `loadedmetadata` es donde deberas extraer la informacion del `video/audio`, *NO* podras hacerlo en ninguna otra parte.

*Nota:* en tu caso quieres cargar audios, pero enrealidad los audios pueden ser cargados tambien desde una etiqueta `video` por ende he preferido usar una etiqueta `video`.

*Nota 2:* la duracion de un `video/audio` esta estimada en segundos (s).

*Nota 3:* los formatos aceptados para un `audio` son limitados, no funcionara en todos los casos, ya que poder extraer esa informacion dependera de si el elemento soporta la carga de ese formato.